# How to determine data types of multiple dictionary values in a JSON file when some values are null

Tags: python, c++, json

The data is a long list of dictionaries from a JSON file. Each dictionary has the same keys but different values of multiple types, and sometimes these values are null. I need to know the type of each value so i can initialize the appropriate variables elsewhere.

An example of data would be like:

```json
[{"Name": null, "Age": 23, "Wage": 16.5},
{"Name": "jason", "Age": null, "Wage": 22.5},
{"Name": "blake", "Age": null, "Wage": 23.8},
{"Name": null, "Age": 26, "Wage": null}]
```

And I'm trying to get the resulting types of each which would be
`<string, int, float>`.

Since the JSON can often be 100,000+ different elements opposed to the 4 in the example, I was not sure if it makes sense to just do something like iterating until all types are determined or if there was a more efficient way. I am currently working in both python and c++.

Comment: `dict_types = list(map(type, dictionary.values()))`?

Comment: `null` is not a value in Python, do you mean `None`?

Comment: lists/arrays in json are not necessary uniform. Either you know what you should have (possibly validated with a json schema), or you got *"random"* json, and you have to treat it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

So to start with working with JSON in python you want to import the json library and you can convert a string to json this will automatically handle datatype conversions. If you are using something like requests library for requesting your data you can use the `.json()` method like demoed in the link below.

```py
result = json.loads('{"Name": null, "Age": 23, "Wage": 16.5}')
print(result)

# {'Name': None, 'Age': 23, 'Wage': 16.5}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-json-python-requests/#

As for determining data types in python you can use the built in method `type()`. You can find all the built in datatypes below.

```py
print(type('example'))

# <class 'str'>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pandas until it doesn't work.

```
data = [{"Name": None, "Age": 23, "Wage": 16.5},
        {"Name": "jason", "Age": None, "Wage": 22.5},
        {"Name": "blake", "Age": None, "Wage": 23.8},
        {"Name": None, "Age": 26, "Wage": None}]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.dtypes)

> Name     object  
> Age     float64  
> Wage    float64  
> dtype: object
```

Or you can use polars, which will return

```
[Utf8, Int64, Float64]
```

100,000 rows should be able to be handled in these tools pretty easily.

---

You probably want to read your file using the library's read function, rather than read the JSON to python list of dicts. Try

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_json("your_file.json")

print(df.dtypes)
```

If you're using newline delimited JSON then you can do a lazy read which should (?) avoid any memory concerns for large files.

```
pl.scan_ndjson("your_file.json").dtypes
```